# c++ reversed integer sequence implementation

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, c++17, template-meta-programming

Who knows how to implement C++ `std::make_index_sequence` reverse version. To get - `make_index_sequence_reverse<int, 5> = <4,3,2,1,0>`. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions .- can you post any attempts you've made?

Comment: @Andrey Avraliov Also accept an answer!

Answer (score 12):

IMHO, there is no reason for a `index_sequence_reverse`: `std::index_sequence` support sequences of indexes and are order neutral (or even without order).

If you can use `std::make_index_sequence`, for a `makeIndexSequenceReverse` you can make something as follows

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto indexSequenceReverse (std::index_sequence<Is...> const &)
   -> decltype( std::index_sequence<sizeof...(Is)-1U-Is...>{} );

template <std::size_t N>
using makeIndexSequenceReverse
   = decltype(indexSequenceReverse(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( std::is_same<std::index_sequence<4U, 3U, 2U, 1U, 0U>,
      makeIndexSequenceReverse<5U>>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: This was not the OP's question, but I would like to note something here: Inverting a sequence with `sizeof...(Is)-1u-Is` only works if the index sequence covers the full range of the original type sequence (e.g., from a tuple). If the index sequence is only a subset, one must consider the size of the original type sequence and the base index of the subset.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with inheritance:

```cpp
template <std::size_t, typename>
struct make_reverse_index_sequence_helper;

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t...NN>
struct make_reverse_index_sequence_helper<N, std::index_sequence<NN...>> 
   : std::index_sequence<(N - NN)...> {};

template <size_t N>
struct make_reverse_index_sequence 
   : make_reverse_index_sequence_helper<N - 1, 
        decltype(std::make_index_sequence<N>{})> {};
```

The helper struct is used to deduce the parameters and apply the subtraction. It can be used just like `std::make_index_sequence` because it derives from `std::index_sequence`, as you can see here:

```cpp
std::index_sequence<4, 3, 2, 1, 0> x = make_reverse_index_sequence<5>{};
```

Comment: This solution is general and consistent with the STL, much appreciated!