# Decrement template parameter inside a fold expression

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename...>
struct C
{ /* ... */ };

template<typename T, unsigned N>
struct B
{
    using type = /* ... */;
};

template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct A
{
    using type = C<typename B<Ts, N-->::type...>; // decrement N sizeof...(Ts) times
};
```

So for example

```
typename A<5, int, long, void>::type
```

expands to

```
C<typename B<int, 5>::type, typename B<long, 4>::type, typename B<void, 3>::type>
```

Since `N` is a `const` value, this code does not compile. Is there any other way?

Comment: It's a constant expression. It's like trying to do `5--`; it's nonsense.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the actual problem (if any) you need to solve? Why do you need to decrement the value?

Comment: BTW, this is not a fold expression.

Comment: please include the error message in the question and please show real code (preferably [mcve]). I find it highly confusing to have `...` from folds and `...` to indicate missing code in the same snippet

Comment: Sounds like you want a [reverse integer sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51408771/c-reversed-integer-sequence-implementation)

Comment: whats wrong with `N-1` ?

Comment: I've edited the answer so that it's a bit clearer

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 They want it to count down, which that wont do.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh thanks.

Comment: @AndyG Doesn't that give the same value every time?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I think I see what you mean about "count down" now. OP does want a reversed integer sequence if that's the case

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subtract a [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) from `N`

```
namespace detail {
    template<size_t N, typename... Ts, size_t... Is>
    C<typename B<Ts, N - Is>::type...> A_impl(std::index_sequence<Is...>);
}

template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct A
{
    using type = decltype(detail::A_impl<N, Ts...>(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}));
};
```

Comment: Looks like a charm.

Comment: Wow this is very similar to what I came up with, even the template argument name for the non-type template `size_t...`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a not-actually-defined-or-invoked templated `static constexpr` helper function:

```
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct A
{
    template<size_t... Is>
    static constexpr auto type_getter(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> C<typename B<Ts, N-Is>::type...>;
    using type = decltype(type_getter(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}));
};
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DfSLikTc5QGmoEHP)